# Read series of integers from cout of one program into cin of another program in C++

Tags: c++

I have found many similar questions, but none with answers that satisfy reading ints. Forgive me if I have overlooked something.

I have a program that outputs a series of 100 space-delimited integers to cout. I have another program that reads integers from cin. My goal is to create a third program that takes 2 arguments, program 1 and program 2, and connects the two, meaning the integers that are output from program 1 serve as input to program 2. I am aware of popen and pstreams, however, they seem to deal with strings. I want to avoid file io. What is the best approach?

Comment: Don't you just need `program1 | program2` in a shell?

Comment: I am unsure. However, the problem I have proposed is simply the base case. The third program will eventually have more responsibility than connecting program 1 with program 2. Does this sound like something  `program1 | program2` can solve?

Comment: I doubt they actually write and read integers from cin and cout. What they probably actually do is write and read strings that represent integral values. Integers are concepts, like three (that is, one more than two). You can't really read and write them, you can only read and write representations of them like "3" or "three" or "III". Those, you might notice, are all strings that represent the integer three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be wise to familiarise yourself with [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

In short, every process gets 3 streams by default:

- *stdin* (input, aka `std::cin`)
- *stdout* (output, aka `std::cout`)
- *stderr* (error, aka `std::cerr`).

Generally speaking the connections between these streams from one process to another is done when the process is invoked (usually through a shell) using something called a pipe (i.e it pipes an output to an input, or input to output etc), which incidently, is usally denoted using the 'pipe' character.

Here is an example, <strike>I will leave the details about 100 space delimited integers for you to implement yourself</strike> **[See EDIT below]**, this just shows the principles of the streams and how different programs use them in situ.

First we define a program called Alice, which outputs a simple phrase...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Alice says hi!";
    return 0;
}
```

Running this from the command line...

```
> Alice
```

We get...

`Alice says hi!`

We then define a program called Bob which will output a phrase and what it receives from *stdin*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string theInput, line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        theInput.append(line);

    std::cout << "Bob says " << theInput;

    return 0;
}
```

The key is how these programs are invoked from the shell.

```
> Alice | Bob
```

The pipe symbol `|` in the command essentially says, take the *stdout* from Alice, and 'pipe' it to *stdin* of Bob program.

Which outputs...

`Bob says Alice says hi!`

Usually you don't use another program to 'connect' streams from different processes (although of course you can invoke the shell from within the 'connecting' program, or even do it programatically), rather, do this during the program(s) invocation.

In relation to your question though, here is an example of the 'third' program (called Eve) which essentially sits in-between Alice and Bob, recieves the stream from Alice, and then outputs a slightly amended version which is piped to Bob to receive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string theInput, line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        theInput.append(line);

    std::cout << "Eve woz 'ere " << theInput;

    return 0;
}
```

Using Eve in-between Alice and Bob, we invoke them as follows...

```
> Alice | Eve | Bob
```

As you can see the output is...

`Bob says Eve woz 'ere Alice says Hi!`

The other stream mentioned (*stderr*) is used to ouptut errors and works in a similar fashion to *stdout*, however means a program can differentiate output errors from normal output.

**EDIT:**

Here are some examples to show how to pass integers around... expanding on the previous examples.

Alice outputs values 1 to 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
    return 0;
}
```

Invoking Alice...

```
> Alice
```

Outputs...

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Bob then recieves the space delimited string of integer values from `stdin`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input, line;
    std::vector<int> values;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        input.append(line);

    std::istringstream iss(input);
    while (iss >> line)
        values.push_back(std::stoi(line));

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << values[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Invoking Alice while piping to Bob...

```
> Alice | Bob
```

Outputs...(note this is Bob outputting the values and not Alice).

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

And finally we have Eve who adds 10 to each value before passing to Bob.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input, line;
    std::vector<int> values;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
        input.append(line);

    std::istringstream iss(input);
    while (iss >> line)
        values.push_back(std::stoi(line) + 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << values[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Invoking Alice, piping to Bob via Eve...

```
> Alice | Eve | Bob
```

Bob outputs...

`11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MattFenlon glad to help, sorry forgot to address the fact you want to work with integers. Yes as mentoned in the comments, only ASCII and Binary are supported so you would need to do this conversion yourself.